# How can I ignore the nested record when it's already deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

- unique_code belongs_to :community
- unique_code belongs_to :user
- user has_many :unique_codes
- community has_many :unique_codes

I want to fetch all the `unique_codes` just like this below

```
@unique_codes = @user.unique_codes
@unique_codes_count = unique_codes.count
```

However, there's sometimes community which is already deleted.
Assume the user had 10 unique_codes, then one community is already deleted.

`@unique_codes_count` returns `10` but I want `9` which is the number of unique_codes of active communities.

How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

**UniqueCode  Model:**

```
class UniqueCode  
    belongs_to :community, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**Controller Code:**

```
   def method_name
     count = 0
     @unique_codes.each do |code|
        if code != nil
          count = count + 1
        end
     end
     puts "This count is giving me the number of unique codes which are not deleted for active community"+count.to_s
   end
```

The count will return the count of rows that do not have null values.

Comment: oh my goodness do you have to calculate like that every time just only to count the number of records whose nested record exist?

Comment: I want to count only when nested community exist. Isn't there any easy way to do in controller? with active Model?

Comment: Looking at the code probably no as '@user.unique_codes' will return all the records that belongs to that user.But you don't want the deleted ones, so check the condition if there is a record with null value and don't count for that.

Comment: I still get `10` any idea?:(

Comment: Thanks. In my case I have 10 unique_codes and 9 communities(one record is deleted). Isn't there any technique to fetch only these 9 friendcodes with ActiveModel?

Comment: Thanks for updating. As I mentioned to shweta, I don't want unique_code to be deleted when related community was deleted:( Because I use Logical Deletion(w/ acts_as_paranoid), and there will be possibility to get it back alive.

Comment: If you don't want unique codes to be deleted then add one column say 'flag' in your table and when you delete any community then update the corresponding `unique codes flag` to false. Then loop through unique codes which have `unique codes true`. That will be your count.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. supposing there will be more than 10000 active user and loading this page, which calculate this loop up to 100 times at one loading. Isn't it too heavy?

Comment: no, the looping can be many times and is instant fast. However, the number of queries you are applying to fetch the result in database should be minimal.

Comment: Thanks then I'll do your way. Thanks:) by the way, I just added `, :dependent => :destroy` to my community model, and deleted one community. But related unique_code didn't  get deleted. why? It only works for the records being created from now on? Not for the record created in the past?

Comment: For the community you are destroying, use -  @community.unique_codes.destroy

Answer (score 1):

Try:

add :dependent => :destroy in community model:

```
has_many :unique_codes, :dependent => :nullify

@unique_codes = @user.unique_codes.where("community_id IS NOT NULL")
@unique_codes_count = @unique_codes.count
```

Comment: I just want to count the number of unique_codes whose nested community exists(not deleted)

Comment: mmm I'm stil getting `10' returned.  "community_id IS NOT NULL" here means the column `community_id` of the table `unique_code` right? It shouldn't be null. Can you probably check the nested? something like "unique_codes.community.title is NOT NULL"

Comment: never mind. I had to add that to my community model not uniquecode model